# Row level formula in Salesforce

Tags: formula

I am looking for some help on building a row-level formula in Salesforce. I have the below formula which is confirmed as valid but I would like to add multiple countries to the Country string rather than just a single one. Whenever I add one, I run into syntax errors. Can anyone help?

```
IF(
    EMPLOYEES >= 1000 && COUNTRY = "DE", 
    "Enteprise", 
    IF(
        (EMPLOYEES > 500 && EMPLOYEES < 1000 && COUNTRY = "DE"), 
        "SMB",
        IF(
            (EMPLOYEES < 500 && COUNTRY = "DE"), 
            "ESMB", 
            NULL
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

While you haven't shown us one of your failed attempts, I'm guessing that you tried to do something like `Country__c = 'DE' || 'FR' || 'UK'`

Formulas aren't too far removed from programming, and you generally can't take shortcuts like that. In most cases, you would need to type everything out explicitly (e.g. `(Country__c = 'DE' || Country__c = 'FR' || Country__c = 'UK')`)

In this particular case though, you can use the `CONTAINS()` function. The first parameter is the "haystack" that you want to search through to try to find the second parameter, the "needle".

```
CONTAINS('DE|FR|UK', Country__c)
```

The pipes (i.e. `|`) between each country code is just to prevent unintended matches. Without them, "RU" would be found and the function would return true (even though we only want DE, FR, or UK in my example).

The other thing worth mentioning here is that when you have something that you keep repeating in a formula (like your country check), you can likely re-arrange things so that you have less repetition.

For your single country example, I would restructure it like so

```
IF(
    COUNTRY = 'DE',
    IF(
        EMPLOYEES >= 1000,
        'Enterprise',
        IF(
            EMPLOYEES >= 500,
            'SMB',
            'ESMB'
        )
    ),
    NULL
)
```

Also note that the "then" and "else" branches of the `IF()` are mutually exclusive (only one of the paths can be chosen). If you get to the `EMPLOYEES >= 500` check, the previous check failing guarantees that there are less than 1000 employees (so you don't need to explicitly check that condition)

Comment: Hi @user:24889, thanks so much for the response. Your single country example worked perfectly. However, I'm running into errors when trying to group single country lookups with multi-country ones. In the below example, I get a 'Syntax error. Extra IF' error. Do you know where I am going wrong?

IF(COUNTRY = 'DE', IF(EMPLOYEES >= 1000,'GB',
IF(EMPLOYEES >= 201,'MM',
IF(EMPLOYEES >= 46,'GRB',
IF(EMPLOYEES >= 11,'SB','ESB')))), NULL
)
IF(CONTAINS('GB|IE', COUNTRY), IF(EMPLOYEES >= 750,'GB',
IF(EMPLOYEES >= 201,'MM',
IF(EMPLOYEES >= 80,'GRB',
IF(EMPLOYEES >= 20,'SB','ESB')))), NULL
)